# Add to cart in magento using SOAP in android

Tags: php, android, soap, magento-1.9, android-ksoap2

Hello I am able to display the list of products in android application , and now its time for me to add the selected products into cart , so I am hereby requesting you to tell me how to add it through android code . Below is the PHP code which i need to convert it to android Java code .

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, 10, array(array(
'product_id' => '4',
'sku' => 'simple_product',
'qty' => '5',
'options' => null,
'bundle_option' => null,
'bundle_option_qty' => null,
'links' => null
)));
```